# Can admin add products to specific customers wishlist via administration?

Tags: magento2, wishlist

Pretty much the title.

Can admin add products to wishlist of specific customer via administration panel? if so, how?

Using magento2 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but it's totally counter intuitive.
Here goes.

- Edit the customer in the backend.
- Click on "create order".
- Click on "add products" on the new screen.
- Select the products you want to add to wishlist and add them to the order (I know, right?).
- Each product, in the order has a dropdown on the right with 3 actions. One of them is what you need: "Move to wishlist". Select it and click on "update items and qty".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your contribution.
Do you know why some products can be added to Wishlist and others can not?

I have checked for product stock status, but there is no difference.

Please see screenshots.
[image: Product can not be added to wishlist. Product SKU is in stock]
[image: Product can not be added to wishlist. Product SKU is in stock]
[image: Product can be added to wishlist. Product SKU is in stock]

Answer (score -1):

No You can't add items from admin panel, you can only remove and configure the ones already there.

Comment: Yes you can. But you have to work for it :)